# How to compress multiple folders into one archive?

Tags: delphi, zip, archive, subdirectory, delphi-xe3

I have some compression components (like KAZip, JVCL, zLib) and exactly know how to use them to compress files, but i want to compress multiple folders into one single archive and keep folders structure after extract, how can i do it?

---

in all those components i just can give a list of files to compress, i can not give struct of folders to extract, there is no way (or i couldn't find) to tell every file must be extracted where:

i have a file named myText.txt in folder FOLDER_A and have a file with same name myText.txt in folder FOLDER_B:

```
|  
|__________ FOLDER_A  
|   |________ myText.txt  
|  
|__________ FOLDER_B  
|   |________ myText.txt  
|
```

i can give a list of files to compress: myList(myText.txt, myText.txt) but i cant give the structure for uncompress files, what is best way to found which file belongs to which folder?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What format are you looking for. FWIW the best tool is tpAbbrevia.

Comment: question modified to be more clear, hope it be. and does tpAbbrevia supports UTF filenames?

Comment: Well, I'd still just use tpAbbrevia. Do you actually care what format the archive is? That's what I was getting at. There are lots of different formats. Will any compression do? What about tar+gzip? Would that be fine for you?

Comment: tpAbbrevia has good Unicode support. Anyway, you can Google just as well as I can to find out stuff like that. Go to the repo, check it out, and start digging!

Comment: format does not matter, i dont care

Comment: Do you at least have some specifications like fastest method, or smallest output?

Comment: http://tpabbrevia.sourceforge.net

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, i can ignore speed and size too, just making archive is important.

Comment: Does it matter if they're actually compressed? Or do you just want multiple files grouped together?

Comment: http://www.delphizip.org has examples how to do it.

Also i think you can split the task of enumerating files and zipping them. For the beginning you just get the list of files that you need: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles then you enumerate them and zip into http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Add - you should strip the "common" beginning of path from ArchiveFileName though.

Comment: If you for example zip `c:\Windows\system32\*.*` then probably filenames should start with `system32\xxx` or even directly with `xxx` w/o even system32 part.

Comment: You enlisted JVCL, but if you have it - you also have Jedi CodeLib installed. And JCL has that class and that method: `function TJclSevenzipCompressArchive.AddDirectory(const PackedName: WideString; const DirName: string = ''; RecurseIntoDir: Boolean = False; AddFilesInDir: Boolean = False): Integer;` - why not just use it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zip format just does not have folders. Well, it kinda does, but they are kind of empty placeholders, only inserted if you need metadata storage like user access rights. But other than those rather rare advanced things - there is no need for folders at all. What is really done - and what you can observe opening zip file in the notepad and scrolling to the end - is that each file has its path in it, starting with "archive root". In your exanple the zip file should have two  entries (two files):

- FOLDER_A/myText.txt
- FOLDER_B/myText.txt

Note, that the separators used are true slashes, common to UNIX world, not back-slashes used in DOS/Windows world. Some libraries would fix back-slashes it for you, some would not - just do your tests.

Now, let's assume that that tree is contained in `D:\TEMP\Project` - just for example.

- D:\TEMP\Project\FOLDER_A\myText.txt
- D:\TEMP\Project\FOLDER_B\myText.txt

There are two more questions (other than path separators): are there more folders within `D:\TEMP\Project\` that should be ignored, rather than zipped (like maybe `D:\TEMP\Project\FOLDER_C\*.*` ? and does your zip-library have direct API to pack the folders wit hall its internal subfolder and files or should you do it file by file ?

Those three questions you should ask yourself and check while choosing the library. The code drafts would be somewhat different.

Now let's start drafting for the libraries themselves:

---

The default variant is just using Delphi itself.

1. Enumerate the files in the folder: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/DirectoriesAndFilesEnumeraion_(Delphi)
2. If that enumeration results in `absolute paths` then strip the common `D:\TEMP\Project` from the beginning: something like `If AnsiStartsText('D:\TEMP\Project\', filename) then Delete(filename, 1, Length('D:\TEMP\Project\'));`. You should get paths relative to chosen containing place. Especially if you do not compress the whole path and live some FOLDER_C out of archive.
3. Maybe you should also call `StringReplace` to change '\' into '/' on filenames
4. then you can zip them using http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Add - take care to specify correct relative `ArchiveFileName` like aforementioned `FOLDER_A/myText.txt`

---

You can use ZipMaster library. It is very VCL-bound and may cause troubles using threads or DLLs. But for simple applications it just works. http://www.delphizip.org/

Last version page have links to "setup" package which had both sources, help and demos. Among demos there is an full-featured archive browser, capable of storing folders. So, you just can read the code directly from it. http://www.delphizip.org/191/v191.html

---

You talked about JVCL, that means you already have Jedi CodeLib installed. And JCL comes with a proper class and function, that judging by name can directly do what you want it too: `function TJclSevenzipCompressArchive.AddDirectory(const PackedName: WideString; const DirName: string = ''; RecurseIntoDir: Boolean = False; AddFilesInDir: Boolean = False): Integer;`

*Actually all those libraries are rather similar on basic level, when i made XLSX export i just made a uniform zipping API, that is used with no difference what an actual zipping engine is installed. But it works with in-memory TStream rather than on-disk files, so would not help you directly. But i just learned than apart of few quirks (like instant vs postponed zipping) on ground level all those libs works the same.*

Comment: @Arioch 'The, Thanks, one of most complete and detailed answers ever, i tried zipMaster, it worked but as you said has threads or DLLs troubles, but JCL worked well with no problem, just needs to set few runtime settings

Comment: @Armin. You're welcome. There is also WinXP native zip, but code samples are usually for VB or C# and translating them to Delphi while not hard, but a bit dull.